# Oracle SQL - creating "unstored" procedure

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have this SQL query

```
SELECT ACCBAL_DATE, ACCBAL_AMOUNT
FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCES t
WHERE ACC_KEY = '964570223'
AND ACCBAL_KEY = '16'
ORDER BY ACCBAL_DATE DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```

It returns one row but I need to use this query for many ACC_KEYS (about 600).

So first way to do that is to run this query about 600x with different ACC_KEY parameter.

The second one is creating a procedure I think.

Procedure which will use variable acc_key and move it to WHERE statement.
Issue is that I can't create procedure stored on server because of permissions.

Is there some way to solve it without storing procedure on server?

EDIT: I know the IN clause but that is not what I need. I need something which will run the query about 600x, each execution with another ACC_KEY in WHERE clause and the output should be 600 rows.

Comment: Where are your ACC_KEYS sourced from?  If it's a table, then obviously it's a join.  If you know them in advance you can make a table and join or `IN` or something.

Comment: I agree with @LoztInSpace; a procedure probably won't fix anything. Another table (with those 600 ACC_KEY values) might/should.

Comment: I have it in excel sheet, when I used them in clause IN, then it will still return only one row. I want to return only one row because without limitations it returns about 100 rows, so I want only the first row which has needed data. For each ACC_KEY it should return only one row, you know..

Comment: How are the keys getting from Excel to your query - are you copying them one by one, or connecting to the DB form with in Excel? It sounds like you want one row per key, which is certainly achievable with a single query and 600 values in an ``IN` clause - though a (possibly derived, or external) table is usually a better choice. It isn't clear if that is actually what you need, so please clarify in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I used them in clause IN, then it will still return only one row. I want to return only one row because without limitations it returns about 100 rows, so I want only the first row which has needed data. For each ACC_KEY it should return only one row

You can still do that with an `IN()` clause listing all 600 key values:

```
select acc_key,
  max(accbal_date) as accbal_date,
  max(accbal_amount) keep (dense_rank last order by accbal_date) as accbal_amount
from account_balances t
where acc_key in ('964570223', '964570224', ...) -- up to 1000 allowed
and accbal_key = '16'
group by acc_key
order by acc_key;
```

This is using aggregate functions and grouping by the key, so you will get one row per key, with the data for the most recent date.

[Read more about keep/last](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/sql-analysis-reporting-data-warehouses.html#GUID-A0B6B93C-F8CB-4BEC-9069-C75C1797D027).

It would still be better to use a collection or a table - maybe an external table loaded from your Excel sheet, saved as a CSV; not least because you can only supply 1000 entries to a single `IN()` clause - or any expression list - but also for performance and readability/maintenance reasons.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the keys in a table or use a derived table in the query.  I would recommend something more like this:

```
WITH keys as (
      SELECT '964570223' as ACC_KEY FROM DUAL UNION ALL
      . . . 
     )
SELECT k.ACC_KEY, MAX(ab.ACCBAL_DATE) as ACCBAL_DATE,
       MAX(ab.ACCBAL_AMOUNT) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY ab.ACCBAL_DATE DESC) as ACCBAL_AMOUNT
FROM keys k LEFT JOIN
     ACCOUNT_BALANCES ab
     ON ab.ACC_KEY = k.ACC_KEY AND
        ab.ACCBAL_KEY = '16'
GROUP BY k.ACC_KEY;
```

Of course the CTE `keys` could be replaced with a table that has the accounts of interest.

Note that this replaces your logic with aggregation logic.  You just want the most recent date and balance, which Oracle supports using the `KEEP` keyword.

Comment: Sorry, I can't understand this complex SQL query.
I just need to something which will run the query about 600x, each execution with another ACC_KEY in WHERE clause and the output should be 600 rows.

Comment: @Stikoun . . . A `JOIN` and `GROUP BY` is not a particularly complex query.

Answer (score 0):

Step-1 : CREATE TABLE WITH 1 COLUMN  ACC_KEY STORES ALL LIST OF ACC_KEY.

Step-2 : Code Run.

```
SELECT T.ACCBAL_DATE, T.ACCBAL_AMOUNT
FROM ACCOUNT_BALANCES t
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT A.ACC_KEY FROM <TABLENAME> A WHERE A.ACC_KEY=T.ACC_KEY)
AND T.ACCBAL_KEY = '16'
ORDER BY T.ACCBAL_DATE DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;
```